# UINavigationController rightbarbuttonitem not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, ios5

after going through the questions related to UINavigationController item i came to post my exact problem ..
firstly i am not add a UINavigationController in `MainWindow.xib` i created and adding UINavigationController in `AppDelegate` file
after that in a `UIViewController` (not in `rootViewController`) class I have to add a rightbarbutton of `Done` type I am
adding it in a searchbarDelegate Method showing as bold:-

```
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {

//This method is called again when the user clicks back from teh detail view.
//So the overlay is displayed on the results, which is something we do not want to happen.

if(exhibDataObj.searching)
    return;

//Add the overlay view.
if(ovController == nil)
    ovController = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

CGFloat yaxis = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;

//Parameters x = origion on x-axis, y = origon on y-axis.
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, yaxis, width, height);
ovController.view.frame = frame;    
ovController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
ovController.view.alpha = 0.5;

ovController.rvController = self;

[self.theTableView insertSubview:ovController.view aboveSubview:self.parentViewController.view];

exhibDataObj.searching = true;
letUserSelectRow = NO;
self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

//Add the done button.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                                          target:self action:@selector(doneSearching_Clicked:)];
 }
```

but this never works .

Any help will be more appreciable.

Comment: In which iOS version you are trying to run the app?

Comment: Do you add your `UINavigationBar` in both `Appdelegate` and `UIViewController`?

Comment: @Jasmine See the question's tags!!!

Comment: @nfarshchi i add the UINavigationController in appDelegate file and access it in all application....

Answer (score 4):

I've tested your code real quick and it seems to be working fine for me, however, I've had the same problem once back then it turned out I was setting the rightBarButtonItem to nil in my viewDidLoad method after setting it to a button. you should make sure your not making the same mistake somehow.

However if that does not work for you you can always try setting a custom button to it:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 30, 30)];

button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"]];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

self.navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customItem;
```

Comment: Brilliant! The last line was the only one that worked for me!!! thanks"

Comment: Same for me, last line fixed it